# sumproduct computation using a matrix (Dataframe) and a vector

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a matrix dataframe with rows and columns-labels

Matrix dataframe (M) in this format below
C1 C2 C3 C4........
R1
R2
R3
R4
..
..

and another vector (C) with values having one row only but with varying order of labels (as below)
C4  C5  C7  C1  C3  C2  C9.....

I need to do a Sum product multiplication of these two and store in a resulting matrix form

R = M * C

The multiplication must be picking the corresponding column labels in the vector (C) and multiply with its right column in M and store it in a new dataframe R
C1 C2 C3 C4......
R1
R2
R3
..

Please advise if there is a faster way and optimal way to perform this task in python.
Should I be using numpy or pandas and which is the best way to perform this task

Data from comments:

```
# matrix M
{'C1': {'R1': 0.007262922, 'R2': 0.161176178, 'R3': 0.036416265, 'R4': 0.088695854},
 'C2': {'R1': 0.00771423, 'R2': 0.151682709, 'R3': 0.038982008, 'R4': 0.083075743},
 'C3': {'R1': 0.00464326, 'R2': 0.104005096, 'R3': 0.040155884, 'R4': 0.085256067},
 'C4': {'R1': 0.006368696, 'R2': 0.189279811, 'R3': 0.025380049, 'R4': 0.019488307},
 'C5': {'R1': 0.007190279, 'R2': 0.219102692, 'R3': 0.020208962, 'R4': 0.023091423},
 'C6': {'R1': 0.012902197, 'R2': 0.188676133, 'R3': 0.022958391, 'R4': 0.024071596}}

# vector C
{'C3': 1.1, 'C1': 3.2, 'C6': 2.4, 'C5': 4.0, 'C2': 3.0, 'C4': 9.0}
```

Comment: Please give a concrete example as per; [mre]

Comment: @MatBailie This is the data for reproducing the task.                                                                   
 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6
R1 0.007262922 0.00771423 0.00464326 0.006368696 0.007190279 0.012902197
R2 0.161176178 0.151682709 0.104005096 0.189279811 0.219102692 0.188676133
R3 0.036416265 0.038982008 0.040155884 0.025380049 0.020208962 0.022958391
R4 0.088695854 0.083075743 0.085256067 0.019488307 0.023091423 0.024071596.
Vector data = C3 C1 C6 C5 C2 C4
1.1 3.2 2.4 4 3 9

Comment: That is not a [mre]. And not even human readable. Please, edit your post to provide a correctly formatted example (a code building an example dataframe; and ideally a code building the wanted result, that we could help optimize; or at least a human readable description of the expected result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) here with a `pd.DataFrame` and a `pd.Series`.  This will multiply by matching the axis index in both variables.

```
# d and s are dictionaries from question
M = pd.DataFrame(d)
C = pd.Series(s)

M.mul(C, axis=1)
#           C1        C2        C3        C4        C5        C6
# R1  0.023241  0.023143  0.005108  0.057318  0.028761  0.030965
# R2  0.515764  0.455048  0.114406  1.703518  0.876411  0.452823
# R3  0.116532  0.116946  0.044171  0.228420  0.080836  0.055100
# R4  0.283827  0.249227  0.093782  0.175395  0.092366  0.057772
```